# How to do site specific configuration with Python Django

Tags: django

At the moment i run some django sites with site specific config by using multiple `settings.py` with different SITE_ID in it and application specifig `APP_OPTION="foo"` settings.

Now i would like to run the sites from one process selecting the site by domain (which is done by `get_current_site`). But in this case they share the global settings.

One option would be of course to patch the applications to use `APP_OPTION[site_id]="foo"`, another option would be to place the settings in the database. Both seem not to be the best solutions to the problem.
Which is the most elegant way to have such site specific config values?

Comment: You might start here: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3041/

Comment: Hmm, i have the site information, the question is where to store (most elegant) the site specific configuration. With this middleware i could try to import site specifig ``settings.py``, but not sure if the app needs to be patched (django.conf.settings should reflect the right site-settings). Anyway, using middleware for this can be a good idea.